# ember add an promise to a rsvp promise because of action

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i have a route that returns several models as such

```
FriendEnemyRouter

model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        friends: this.store.find('People', ...),
        enemies: this.store.find('People', ..),
```

On the same router theres an action (Its on the router because it does store 'things')

```
actions: {
     findMoreFriends: function(param, param) {
         var newFriends = this.store.find('People', ..); 
         var newPromise = this.controller.get('model'); //OK. Inspecting sees above friends and enemies. What type is it?

         model.set("newFriends": newPromise); // throws an exception
         //-- or --
         model.newFriends = newPromise; // no exception but observer (computer property) on the controller is not fired.
     }
 }
```

Ultimately i wish this computed property on the controller to fire

```
 FriendEnemyController

  computedNewFriends: function() {
       ....
   ).property('newFriends');
```

What is the procedure for adding new promises to rsvp promises...not even sure the object types...

```
         model.set("newFriends": newPromise); // throws an exception
         model.newFriends = newPromise; // no exception but clearly doesnt notify observer/property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSVP.hash` resolves a `POJO`, meaning it doesn't extend `Ember.Object`.  As such `set` and `get` aren't defined on the object itself.  You can use `Ember.set` and `Ember.get` on objects which aren't Ember Objects, and it will trigger computed properties.

```
Ember.set(model, 'newFriends', newPromise)
```

Comment: Thank you. Works as desired. Interestingly, this also works from router. `this.set("controller.model.newFriends", newPromise);`